# Run Scrapy spiders via twisted inlineCallbacks

Tags: python, twisted, scrapy, reactor

I have `ImportError: No module named 'spiders'` so i think there are no environment variables when the spider call happens. But i don't fully understand how can i make them to work correctly.

Basically, I want to run some Scrapy spiders, they will populate the db, and then my program should make small calculations. This should happen regularly (say each minute). As twisted already in scrapy dependencies, i decided to combine this. 
The project structure is like (simplistically):

```
 -Project
        |-src
            |- __init__.py
            |- spiders.py
        |-bot.py
```

In spiders.py i have 2 separate spiders, and they work well when i start them within that file.
But now i put some logic in bot.py and come up with:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue

from src.spiders import first_spider, second_spider

def do_some_stuff(): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

    @inlineCallbacks
    def cycle():
        yield runner.crawl(first_spider)
        yield runner.crawl(second_spider)
        returnValue(do_some_stuff())


    timeout = 60.0

    l = task.LoopingCall(cycle)
    l.start(timeout)

    reactor.run()
```

And the error trace:

```
    2017-04-21 15:32:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole']
2017-04-21 15:32:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-04-21 15:32:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-04-21 15:32:26 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2017-04-21 15:32:26 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "projectpath/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "projectpath/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "projectpath/bot.py", line 141, in cycle
    yield runner.crawl(first_spider)
ImportError: No module named 'spiders'
```

**Update.** Imports in spiders.py:

```
import hashlib
import json

import pymongo
import scrapy

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

Comment: Hm.. nothing changes. The same error.

Comment: Can you share the imports in your `spiders.py` file? Anyhow, here's a [link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?highlight=CrawlerRunner#run-scrapy-from-a-script) to run scrapy spiders from a script. I think it might be useful as a reference.

Comment: try `from Project.src.spiders import first_spider, second_spider`

Comment: added imports from spiders.py

Answer (score 1):

So your project structure is

```
.
├── bot.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── spiders.py
```

To run it you should use [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) as follows

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python3 bot.py
```

And here is a functional one-file based scrapy project which will do looping scrape every 60 seconds.

```
# scraper.py
import datetime
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open(spider.settings['JSON_FILE'], 'a')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item

class QuoteItem(Item):
    text = Field()
    author = Field()
    tags = Field()
    spider = Field()

class QuotesSpiderOne(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes1"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/', ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').get()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            item['spider'] = self.name
            yield item

class QuotesSpiderTwo(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes2"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/', ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').get()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            item['spider'] = self.name
            yield item

def do_some_stuff():
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

@inlineCallbacks
def cycle():
    yield runner.crawl(QuotesSpiderOne)
    yield runner.crawl(QuotesSpiderTwo)
    return do_some_stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = dict()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    settings['HTTPCACHE_ENABLED'] = True
    settings['JSON_FILE'] = 'items.jl'
    settings['ITEM_PIPELINES'] = dict()
    settings['ITEM_PIPELINES']['__main__.JsonWriterPipeline'] = 800

    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings=settings)
    timeout = 60.0

    l = task.LoopingCall(cycle)
    l.start(timeout)

    reactor.run()
```

To run it

```
$ python3 scraper.py
```

One advantage of one-file scrapy project is the ease of generating [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) binary.

An alternative looping logic can be constructed with [`reactor.callLater`](https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-19.10.0/core/howto/time.html#scheduling-tasks-for-the-future). This one allows modification of `timeout` within the `cycle`.

```
# above code stays the same

@inlineCallbacks
def cycle(runner, timeout):
    yield runner.crawl(QuotesSpiderOne)
    yield runner.crawl(QuotesSpiderTwo)
    do_some_stuff()
    reactor.callLater(timeout, cycle, runner, timeout)

def main():
    settings = dict()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    settings['HTTPCACHE_ENABLED'] = True
    settings['JSON_FILE'] = 'items.jl'
    settings['ITEM_PIPELINES'] = dict()
    settings['ITEM_PIPELINES']['__main__.JsonWriterPipeline'] = 800

    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings=settings)
    timeout = 60.0

    reactor.callLater(timeout, cycle, runner, timeout)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```